# openvpn server drops route for client

Tags: openvpn

I am using the following openvpn config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/openvpn-server.crt
key keys/openvpn-server.key
dh keys/dh1024.pem
crl-verify keys/crl.pem
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
server 172.29.3.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
client-to-client
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4 
push "route 172.50.0.0 255.255.252.0"
```

In the /etc/openvpn/ccd directory I have some files that contain `ipconfig-push` directives like so:

```
ifconfig-push 172.29.3.74 172.29.3.1
```

I have something like this in my openvpn-status.log:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Thu Jul  3 12:24:18 2014
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
host01,<public ip>:41283,6597296,9666006,Thu Jul  3 11:48:06  11:31:15    2014
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
172.29.3.74,host1,<public ip>:41283,Thu Jul  3 12:24:17 2014
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,1
END
```

The problem is that after some time, the vpn server drops that route, so I only get the entry for `host01` in the OpenVPN CLIENT LIST but not in the routing table.

In the logs I only get the message:

Jul  3 06:47:39 ovpn-server[32764]: host1/:56293 MULTI: bad source address from client [172.29.3.74], packet dropped

After the route is dropped, so obviously the vpn server does not recognize that host because it doesn't know where to route the package.

Do you know what can be wrong with my setup that makes the vpn server drop routes?

Comment: Try to investigate when this is happening. Is it possible that another client connects and gets the same IP address assigned? Does it happen after a rekey or a reconnect?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Somehow two clients are getting the same ip addres... Thank you.. don't know how to solve this tho.

Comment: does the client with the conflicting IP address have a CCD `ifconfig-push` entry?